# Why it cannot get tickers data by lapply with getSymbol function?

Tags: r, stock, yahoo-finance, quantmod

When I run the R code below, the tickerd_data only get the name of "AAPL" and "MSFT" as a list.

```
library(quantmod)
tickers <- c("AAPL","MSFT")
tickers_data <- lapply(tickers, function(x) { getSymbols(x, src = "yahoo", auto.assign = TRUE)})
```

> print(tickers_data)
> [[1]]
> [1] "AAPL"

[[2]]
[1] "MSFT"

How can I get the tickers data set in to tcikers_data as a list with 2 stocks data saved?

Comment: Quantmod objects are typically matrices rather than lists.

Comment: You could use `as.data.frame`

Comment: Use `auto.assign=FALSE` . That will cause it to return a list of xts objects.

Comment: Or even better is `ticker_names <- getSymbols(tickers, env = e <- new.env());
ticker_data <- as.list(e); rm(e)`

Comment: It works to load the 2 symbol data into tickers_data as a list. Thanks. 
tickers <- c("AAPL","MSFT")
tickers_data <- lapply(tickers, function(x) { getSymbols(x, src = "yahoo", auto.assign = FALSE)})